# How to pass value from one kivy screen to another?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to develop a **financial calculation app in Kivy**. Right now, I struggle with passing the calculation result (stored in a  text input widget text_input_4) of the screen "compound" to the screen "inflation". My goal is to retrieve the results of the previous screen and autofill text_input_1 of the inflation page. Therefore, I tried to do accomplish that in the **on_enter()** of the **class Inflation_Screen**.

This is the traceback I receive:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdNHe.png)

Below, I share with you the kivy app and the corresponding kv file.

```
import sqlite3
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
import kivymd
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp

# # https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gt0_BuJmJeI




Window.size = (1000, 700)

kv = """
ScreenManager:
    Login:
    HomeScreen:
    CompoundScreen:
    InflationScreen:
    RetirementScreen:
    DatabaseTableScreen:
    SecretScreen:
    Date: 
<HomeScreen>
    name: 'home'
    Screen:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
<CompoundScreen>
    name: 'compound'
    id: compound
    Screen:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size: root.width, root.height
            GridLayout:
                cols: 2
                Label:
                    id: label_1
                    text: "Monthly Investment [€]"
                    font_size: 30
                    background_color: (0,0,0,1)
                    canvas.before:
                        Color: 
                            rgba: self.background_color
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                    color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                    bold: True
                    italic: True
                    outline_color: (0,0,0)
                    outline_width: 3
                TextInput:
                    id: text_input_1
                    multiline: False
                    font_size: 30
                Label:
                    id: label_2
                    text: "Interest Rate [%]"
                    font_size: 30
                    background_color: (0,0,0,1)
                    canvas.before:
                        Color: 
                            rgba: self.background_color
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                    color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                    bold: True
                    italic: True
                    outline_color: (0,0,0)
                    outline_width: 3
                TextInput:
                    id: text_input_2
                    multiline: False
                    font_size: 30  
                Label:
                    id: label_3
                    text: "Years"
                    font_size: 30
                    background_color: (0,0,0,1)
                    canvas.before:
                        Color: 
                            rgba: self.background_color
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                    color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                    bold: True
                    italic: True
                    outline_color: (0,0,0)
                    outline_width: 3
                TextInput:
                    id: text_input_3
                    multiline: False
                    font_size: 30   
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                Button:
                    id: button_1
                    text: "Calculate results"
                    font_size: 30
                    on_release:
                        print("Calculation is starting.")
                        root.calculate_results()
            GridLayout:
                cols: 2
                Label:
                    id: label_4
                    text: "SUM [€]"
                    font_size: 30
                    background_color: (0,0,0,1)
                    canvas.before:
                        Color: 
                            rgba: self.background_color
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                    color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                    bold: True
                    italic: True
                    outline_color: (0,0,0)
                    outline_width: 3
                TextInput:
                    id: text_input_4
                    multiline: False
                    font_size: 30
                Label:
                    id: label_5
                    text: "Paid [€]"
                    font_size: 30
                    background_color: (0,0,0,1)
                    canvas.before:
                        Color: 
                            rgba: self.background_color
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                    color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                    bold: True
                    italic: True
                    outline_color: (0,0,0)
                    outline_width: 3
                TextInput:
                    id: text_input_5
                    multiline: False
                    font_size: 30  
                Label:
                    id: label_6
                    text: "Value Increase [€]"
                    font_size: 30
                    background_color: (0,0,0,1)
                    canvas.before:
                        Color: 
                            rgba: self.background_color
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                    color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                    bold: True
                    italic: True
                    outline_color: (0,0,0)
                    outline_width: 3
                TextInput:
                    id: text_input_6
                    multiline: False
                    font_size: 30
            GridLayout:
                cols: 4
                Button:
                    id: button_2
                    text: "Go to database"
                    font_size: 30
                    on_release:
                        root.display_database_entries()
                Button:
                    id: button_3
                    text: "Delete db"
                    font_size: 30
                Button:
                    id: button_4
                    text: "Graph"
                    on_release:
                        root.move_to_home_screen()
                    font_size: 30
                Button:
                    id: button_5
                    text: "Inflation"
                    font_size: 30
                    on_release:
                        root.manager.current = 'inflation'  
<InflationScreen>
    name: 'inflation'
    Screen:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size: root.width, root.height
            GridLayout:
                cols: 2
                Label:
                    id: label_1
                    text: "Capital [€]"
                    font_size: 30
                    background_color: (0,0,0,1)
                    canvas.before:
                        Color: 
                            rgba: self.background_color
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                    color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                    bold: True
                    italic: True
                    outline_color: (0,0,0)
                    outline_width: 3
                TextInput:
                    id: text_input_1
                    multiline: False
                    font_size: 30
                Label:
                    id: label_2
                    text: "Years"
                    font_size: 30
                    background_color: (0,0,0,1)
                    canvas.before:
                        Color: 
                            rgba: self.background_color
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                    color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                    bold: True
                    italic: True
                    outline_color: (0,0,0)
                    outline_width: 3
                TextInput:
                    id: text_input_2
                    multiline: False
                    font_size: 30  
                Label:
                    id: label_3
                    text: "Exp. inflation rate [%]"
                    font_size: 30
                    background_color: (0,0,0,1)
                    canvas.before:
                        Color: 
                            rgba: self.background_color
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                    color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                    bold: True
                    italic: True
                    outline_color: (0,0,0)
                    outline_width: 3
                TextInput:
                    id: text_input_3
                    multiline: False
                    font_size: 30 
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                Button:
                    id: button_1
                    text: "Calculate money worth after inflation"
                    font_size: 30
                    on_release:
                        root.calculate_money_worth_after_inflation(float(text_input_1.text), float(text_input_2.text),
                        float(text_input_3.text))
            GridLayout:
                cols: 2
                Label:
                    id: label_4
                    text: "Capital after inflation [€]"
                    font_size: 30
                    background_color: (0,0,0,1)
                    canvas.before:
                        Color: 
                            rgba: self.background_color
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                    color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                    bold: True
                    italic: True
                    outline_color: (0,0,0)
                    outline_width: 3
                TextInput:
                    id: text_input_4
                    multiline: False
                    font_size: 30
                Label:
                    id: label_5
                    text: "% of capital before infl. [%]"
                    font_size: 30
                    background_color: (0,0,0,1)
                    canvas.before:
                        Color: 
                            rgba: self.background_color
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                    color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                    bold: True
                    italic: True
                    outline_color: (0,0,0)
                    outline_width: 3
                TextInput:
                    id: text_input_5
                    multiline: False
                    font_size: 30 
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                Button:
                    id: button_2
                    text: "Go to Retirement Calculator"
                    font_size: 30
                    on_release:
                        root.manager.current = 'retirement'        
                                       
"""


class StartApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return screen


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass


class Login(Screen):
    ben = StringProperty()
    pw = StringProperty()
    button = ObjectProperty()

    def move_to_compound_screen(self):
        print("Hallelujah")
        ms.current = "compound"
        ms.transition.direction = "right"

    def login_popup(self):
        if self.ben == "" or self.pw == "":
            popup = Popup(title='Error',
                          content=Label(text="No user name or password was passed!"),
                          size_hint =(None,None), size=(400,400))
            popup.open()
        else:
            if self.ben == "Python" and self.pw == "1234":
                self.button.background_color = [0., 1., 0., 1.]
            else:
                self.button.background_color = [1., 0., 0., 1.]


class SecretScreen(Screen):
    pass
  

class DatabaseHandling:
    def __init__(self, database_name, table_name, table_column1, table_column1_datatype,
                 table_column2, table_column2_datatype, table_column3, table_column3_datatype,
                 table_column4, table_column4_datatype, table_column5, table_column5_datatype,
                 table_column6, table_column6_datatype):
        self.database_name = database_name
        self.table_name = table_name
        self.table_column1 = table_column1
        self.table_column1_datatype = table_column1_datatype
        self.table_column2 = table_column2
        self.table_column2_datatype = table_column2_datatype
        self.table_column3 = table_column3
        self.table_column3_datatype = table_column3_datatype
        self.table_column4 = table_column4
        self.table_column4_datatype = table_column4_datatype
        self.table_column5 = table_column5
        self.table_column5_datatype = table_column5_datatype
        self.table_column6 = table_column6
        self.table_column6_datatype = table_column6_datatype

    def process_and_output_data(self):
        stored_list = self.output_database_results_on_screen()
        return stored_list

    def connect_to_database(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(f'{self.database_name}.db')
        return conn

    def create_new_database(self):
        # create a database or connect to existing one
        conn = self.connect_to_database()
        # create cursor
        c = conn.cursor() # cursors is a helper that is sent off and comes back with result
        # create table
        c.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE {self.table_name} (
            {self.table_column1} {self.table_column1_datatype}, 
            {self.table_column2} {self.table_column2_datatype},
            {self.table_column3} {self.table_column3_datatype}, 
            {self.table_column4} {self.table_column4_datatype}, 
            {self.table_column5} {self.table_column5_datatype},
            {self.table_column6} {self.table_column6_datatype}
            )""")

        # commit changes
        conn.commit()
        # close connection
        conn.close()

    # deletes all entries from table
    def delete_entries(self):
        conn = self.connect_to_database()
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(f"DELETE FROM {self.table_name}")
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        store_data = self.process_and_output_data() # attempt to get current entries from db

    def output_database_results_on_screen(self):
        conn = self.connect_to_database()
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM {}".format(self.table_name))
        rows = c.fetchall()
        store_data = []
        for row in rows:
            print(row)
            store_data.append(row)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        return store_data

    def submit_data_to_database(self, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6):
        try:
            self.create_new_database()
        except:
            # connect to database
            conn = self.connect_to_database()
            # create cursor
            c = conn.cursor()  # cursors is a helper that is sent off and comes back with result
            # insert data into table table
            c.execute(f"INSERT INTO {self.table_name} "
                      f"({self.table_column1}, {self.table_column2}, {self.table_column3}, {self.table_column4}, "
                      f"{self.table_column5}, {self.table_column6}) "
                      f"VALUES({value1}, {value2}, {value3}, "
                      f"{value4}, {value5}, {value6})")
            # commit changes
            conn.commit()
            # close connection
            conn.close()

            # TODO: Check if try except block works

    def delete_table_from_database(self):
        # delete sqlite table from database
        # create a database or connect to existing one
        conn = self.connect_to_database()
        # create cursor
        c = conn.cursor() # cursors is a helper that is sent off and comes back with result
        # drop table from database
        c.execute(f"DROP TABLE {self.table_name}")
        # commit changes
        conn.commit()
        # close connection
        conn.close()


class CompoundScreen(Screen):
    my_db_handler = DatabaseHandling('FreakyDatabase', 'MoneyTable', 'monthlyInvest', 'real', 'interestRate',
                                     'real', 'years', 'real', 'finalSum', 'real', 'sumPaid', 'real', 'valueIncrease',
                                     'real')

    def calculate_results(self):
        monthly_saving_amount = float(self.ids.text_input_1.text)
        interest_rate_per_year = float(self.ids.text_input_2.text)
        years = float(self.ids.text_input_3.text)
        print(monthly_saving_amount, interest_rate_per_year, years)
        try:
            sum_final = self.calculate_sum_final(monthly_saving_amount, interest_rate_per_year, years)
            sum_paid = self.calculate_paid_amount(monthly_saving_amount, years)
            increase = self.calculate_value_increase(sum_final, sum_paid)
            return sum_final, sum_paid, increase
        except ValueError:
            print('ERROR: You cannot convert string to float. Probably due to empty entry field.')

    def calculate_paid_amount(self, monthly_saving_amount, years):
        months = self.calculate_months(years)
        sum_paid = monthly_saving_amount * months
        self.ids.text_input_5.text = str(round(sum_paid, 2))
        print(f"Sum Paid: {sum_paid: 0.2f} €")
        return sum_paid

    def calculate_value_increase(self, sum_final, sum_paid):
        increase = sum_final - sum_paid
        self.ids.text_input_6.text = str(round(increase, 2))
        print(f"Value Increase: {increase: 0.2f} €")
        self.my_db_handler.submit_data_to_database(str(self.ids.text_input_1.text), str(self.ids.text_input_2.text),
                                                   str(self.ids.text_input_3.text), str(self.ids.text_input_4.text),
                                                   str(self.ids.text_input_5.text), str(self.ids.text_input_6.text))
        return increase

    def calculate_sum_final(self, monthly_saving_amount, interest_rate_per_year, years):
        months = self.calculate_months(float(years))
        print("months = ", months)
        a = self.calculate_monthly_interest_rate(float(interest_rate_per_year))
        q = self.calculate_q_factor(a)
        sum_final = float(monthly_saving_amount) * q * ((q  ** months) - 1) / (q -1)
        print("sum final = ", sum_final)
        self.ids.text_input_4.text = str(round(sum_final,2))
        return sum_final

    def calculate_months(self, years):
        months = years * 12
        return months

    def calculate_monthly_interest_rate(self, yearly_interest_rate):
        monthly_interest_rate = 100 * (((1 + (yearly_interest_rate / 100)) ** (1 / float(12))) - 1)
        return monthly_interest_rate

    def calculate_q_factor(self, monthly_interest_rate):
        q = 1 + (monthly_interest_rate / 100)
        return q

    def move_to_inflation_screen(self):
        print("You are transferred to the inflation screen")
        ms.current = "inflation"
        ms.transition.direction = "right"

    def display_database_entries(self):
        stored_data = self.my_db_handler.output_database_results_on_screen()
        print("You are transferred to the database screen")
        ms.current = "database"

    def move_to_home_screen(self):
            ms.current = "home"
            ms.transition.direction = "right"


class InflationScreen(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *largs):
        compound_screen = ms.get_screen('compound')
        self.ids.text_input_1.text = str(300)
        # self.ids.text_input_1.text = compound_screen.text4
        print("-------TEST---- This is what's inside text 4", compound_screen.ids.text_input_4.text)
        self.ids.text_input_2.text = compound_screen.text3
        # This passes the value from the previous screen page to the inflation screen

    def calculate_money_worth_after_inflation(self, capital, years, exp_inflation_rate):
        purchasing_power_decrease = 1 - (1 / (1 + (exp_inflation_rate / 100)))
        new_capital_value = capital * ((1 - purchasing_power_decrease) ** years)
        new_capital_value = round(new_capital_value, 2)
        percentage_of_initial_money = self.percentage_of_initial_capital_before_inflation(new_capital_value, capital)
        percentage_of_initial_money *= 100
        percentage_of_initial_money = round(percentage_of_initial_money, 2)
        print(f"I will calculate it all for you: \n"
              f"Capital: {capital}, "
              f"\nyears: {years},"
              f" Exp. Inflation: {exp_inflation_rate} -->"
              f"\nNew purchasing capital value: {new_capital_value}."
              f"\nThis means, due to inflation your money is only worth {percentage_of_initial_money} % of the "
              f"initial capital.")
        self.ids.text_input_4.text = str(new_capital_value)
        self.ids.text_input_5.text = str(percentage_of_initial_money)
        return new_capital_value

    def percentage_of_initial_capital_before_inflation(self, new_capital, original_capital):
        result = new_capital / original_capital
        result = round(result, 2)
        return result

    def move_to_retirement_screen(self):
        print("You are transferred to the retirement screen")
        ms.current = "retirement"
        ms.transition.direction = "right"


class RetirementScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *largs):
        inflation_screen = ms.get_screen('inflation')
        self.ids.text_input_1.text = inflation_screen.ids.text_input_4.text
        # This passes the value from the previous screen page to the retirement screen

    def calculate_earnings(self, retirement_capital_after_inflation, retirement_years, retirement_share_person_1,
                           retirement_share_person_2):
        retirement_share_1_in_decimal = self.calculate_share_in_decimal(retirement_share_person_1)
        retirement_share_2_in_decimal = self.calculate_share_in_decimal(retirement_share_person_2)

        avg_pension_per_year = (retirement_capital_after_inflation / retirement_years)

        avg_pension_person1_per_year = (avg_pension_per_year * retirement_share_1_in_decimal)
        avg_pension_person2_per_year = (avg_pension_per_year * retirement_share_2_in_decimal)

        avg_pension_person1_per_month = avg_pension_person1_per_year / 12
        avg_pension_person1_per_month = round(avg_pension_person1_per_month, 2)
        avg_pension_person2_per_month = avg_pension_person2_per_year / 12
        avg_pension_person2_per_month = round(avg_pension_person2_per_month, 2)

        self.ids.text_input_5.text = str(avg_pension_person1_per_month)
        self.ids.text_input_6.text = str(avg_pension_person2_per_month)

    def calculate_share_in_decimal(self, share):
        result = share / 100
        retirement_share = round(result, 2)
        return retirement_share

    def calculate_remaining_share_person(self):
        if self.ids.text_input_3.text.isdigit():
            share_person_2 = 100 - float(self.ids.text_input_3.text)
        else:
            share_person_2 = 100
            self.ids.text_input_3.text = str(0)
        self.ids.text_input_4.text = str(share_person_2)
        return share_person_2


ms = ScreenManager()
ms.add_widget(Login(name='login'))
ms.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='home'))
ms.add_widget(SecretScreen(name='secret'))
ms.add_widget(Date(name='date'))
ms.add_widget(CompoundScreen(name='compound'))
ms.add_widget(InflationScreen(name='inflation'))
ms.add_widget(RetirementScreen(name='retirement'))
ms.add_widget(DatabaseTableScreen(name='database'))


if __name__=='__main__':
    StartApp().run()
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction or know how to access the text of text_input_4? Thanks in advance!

Best,

Maximilian

Answer (score 0):

You can access it using below command:

```
value = InflationScreen.ids.text_input_4.text
```

This will give you the text of `text_input_4` in value variable.

Comment: Dear Vaibhav, thank you for helping me out. I took your advice and adapted your code to my needs: I simply try to print out the text of text input 4 to the console and work from there. Thus, I changed the on_enter() of the Inflation Screen to the following:                                                        
 print("-------TEST---- This is what's inside text 4", CompoundScreen.ids.text_input_4.text)
 AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.DictProperty' object has no attribute 'text_input_4'. Does that AttributeError mean that I need to specify the text input property within the Compund class?

Comment: Here's my new Traceback:                                                                             
 AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.DictProperty' object has no attribute 'text_input_4'.  
 Does that AttributeError mean that I need to specify the text input property within the Compound class?